# Do I need a special license to distribute a Mono executable cross compiled with mkbundle?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm not a C# developer myself, but I had to use a SDK meant to be used with .NET so I made a Mono application and cross compiled it to run on Windows, Mac, and Linux using the method described here: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/mkbundle/.

It works as expected, but as stated here: https://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/ you may have to have a commercial licence from Xamarin, but it was last updated on 2014. Other sources and forums mention Novell, I think thats even older info.

Reading the Mono license on github it says it is "mainly" MIT: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/LICENSE

So, I do I need to buy some kind of license to distribute a commercial self-contained executable cross compiled with mkbundle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at "archived" content on the Mono site. Mono was dual-licensed but that when Microsoft acquired Xamarin, they remove the dual-license and re-licensed it.

> March 31, 2016 At Microsoft Build today, we announced that we are re-releasing Mono under the MIT license and have contributed it to the .NET Foundation. >

re: https://www.mono-project.com/news/2016/03/31/mono-relicensed-mit/

Mono maintains a FAQ on the current licensing status:

- https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/licensing/